# cannot use 'TVICameraCapturer'

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

I'm migrating my app into iOS 13 , swift 5.0.

The main feature in my app is video calling which was working great.

I was using `TVICameraCapturer` in order to add the video track.

using the below methods:

```
var camera : TVICameraCapturer!

guard let camera = TVICameraCapturer(source: .backCameraWide), let videoTrack = LocalVideoTrack(capturer: camera) else {
        return
}
```

any way after migrating and fixing all errors, there remains 1 thing, that I couldn't find

`'TVICameraCapturer'` please can anyone help if it's obsoleted and give any alternative.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is been changed in recent versions of TwilioVideo CameraSource is the type you are looking for.